# Laravel - Querying related model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Basically I am trying to execute the following query.

```
Volunteer::with('user')
->where('fname', 'like', '%' . Input::get('search') . '%')
->orWhere('lname', 'like', '%' . Input::get('search') . '%')
->orWhere('users.email', 'like', '%' . Input::get('search') . '%') //error
->orWhere('phone', 'like', '%' . Input::get('search') . '%')
->orderBy('fname')
->paginate($limit);
```

The second `onWhere` clause throws `column not found` error.

volunteers and users table are related.

How do I use email column from users table while querying volunteers table like shown above.

Please help. Any workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do is [query the relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations). For this example it can be accomplished like this:

```
Volunteer::with('user')
->where('fname', 'like', '%' . Input::get('search') . '%')
->orWhere('lname', 'like', '%' . Input::get('search') . '%')
->orWhereHas('user', function($query){
    $query->where('email', 'like', '%' . Input::get('search') . '%');
})
->orWhere('phone', 'like', '%' . Input::get('search') . '%')
->orderBy('fname')
->paginate($limit);
```

Comment: Exactly. A way to query the relationship. Million Thanks. :)

Comment: Can you please help me with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26014364/laravel-php-returning-redirecting-from-child-class